# Show decimal on a division even if it results to a whole number

Tags: c++

I would like a way to force at least 1 decimal to appear in the result of an integer division.

```
int a = 2, b = 1;
std::cout << a/(double)b;
>>>> 2
```

```
int a = 2, b = 1;
std::cout << (1.0*a)/(1.0*b);
>>>> 2
```

I would like to print 2.0 but only gets 2 trying above tricks.

Answer:

```
std::cout.precision(1);
std::cout << std::fixed << a/(double)b;
```

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpoint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpoint)

Comment: Even an integer division should produce `2` so I have no idea why you're getting that output.

Comment: @MarkRansom ofc, typo. Thanks for noticing.